# I get a dimension error which makes no sense "expected shape = "

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

So I have made the following implementation of the unet model:

```
def unet_model(optimizer, loss_metric, metrics, sample_width, sample_height, lr=1e-3):
    inputs = Input((sample_width, sample_height, 1))
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(pool1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(pool2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    drop3 = Dropout(0.3)(pool3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.3)(pool4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv5), conv4], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    up7 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv6), conv3], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    up8 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv7), conv2], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    up9 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1], axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer(lr=lr), loss=loss_metric, metrics=metrics)
    return model
```

and I also have a dataloader to load images in the form of (1024, 1024,1) as in:

```
# Load datasets
train_input, train_output = dataloader(filepath, "train")
test_input, test_output = dataloader(filepath, "test")
print(train_input.shape)
print(train_output.shape)
print(test_input.shape)
print(test_output.shape)

# Load model
model = unet_model(optimizer=Adam, loss_metric=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef], sample_width=train_input.shape[0], sample_height=train_input.shape[1],lr=1e-3)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[])
history = model.fit(x=train_input, y=train_output, epochs=30)
```

but when i run it i get teh following output:

```
(1024, 1024, 129)
(1024, 1024, 129)
(1024, 1024, 18)
(1024, 1024, 18)
Epoch 1/30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2825, in variable_creator_scope
    yield
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:754 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /home/tzikos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:271 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) +
    ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 1024, 1024, 1), found shape=(32, 1024, 129)
```

so it enters into the training epoch but is unable to run through it, and for some reason it loses one of its dimensions intrinsically in the network, and i dont get where or how. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Seems your data is missing the samples dimension (it should be one even if its one sample), and the input shape does not match, compare between your Input layer and your data (specially the last dimension, 1 vs 129)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy shouldnt it have the size (sample_width, sample_height,1) to be getting the images 1 by 1? Im not sure I am following you.

Comment: No, a single image should be (1, w, h, c), where c is the number of channels.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Snoopy, that solved part of the problem but the expected shape is still wrong. I get :
    ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 1024, 1024, 1), found shape=(32, 1024, 1, 129).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I got it thx a bunch !!!